# How to move table view in navigation controller

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a navigation controller and when I place an image for navigation bar by hiding it the  table view which is below the navigation bar it is moving upside and first row is hide by the image. I  want that (row) table   to move down.

If I am not hiding the navigation bar its working correctly and the image also added above the navigation bar perfectly but I am not able to see the navigation bar back button on the next screen because whatever image I added  was covering this bar.

How can I remove this image if we cannot move the tableview in first view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are trying to put an image into a navbar's title, as it sounds..a much simpler way is:

```
UIImageView *headerImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myimage.png"]];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = headerImageView;
    [headerImageView release];
```

Comment: yes its working but iam unable to see my full image my image hieght is
45;